# Optimizing a function in a loop

Tags: r, optimization, time-series

I am trying to deal with a likelihood function from an AR(2) model.
I have to maximize a function with respect to two variables, alpha1 and alpha2.
Since it is about time series, I have the variable x stored in a matrix for 200 time periods.
I have 10000 simulations of this. So I have the x values in a 200x10000 matrix.
I want to directly have a matrix of 2x10000 in which the results of the optimization for every simulation are stored. I have set a for loop and I have specified the function inside of it, but it is not working, i.e. when I run it it tells me:

```
Error in A <- -optim(c(1.5, 0.75), log_lik) : argument not valid for operator
```

I attach here my code. I have created a function to contain the results before running the loop and I have called it A:

```
for (i in 1:R) {
 for (t in 3:N) {
  log_lik <- function (α) {
    α1 <- α[1]
    α2 <- α[2]
    L = -1/2*((N-2)*log(pi*2)+(N-2)*log(1)+sum((x[t,i]-c-α1*x[t-1,i]-α2*x[t-2,i])^2))
  }
  A <- -optim(c(1.5, 0.75), log_lik)$par
 }
 return(A)
}
```

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `optim` expects, as argument, 
a 1-argument function (whose argument can be a 2-element vector):
try 
`log_lik <- function(p) { α1 <- p[1]; α2 <- p[2]; ... }`.

Comment: I updated the text, it still gives me trouble :(

Comment: `optim` returns a list: you want its `par` element: `A <- - optim(...)$par`.

Comment: I had not used R in a while, so now I see that forgetting par was quite dumb.. thank you!